# PSRemoteRegistry.psm1 is not digitally signed

Tags: powershell

Hi Guys I am new to all of this but have done a few batch files or cmd files. and used to program IVRs.

I am not involved in SQL and IIS but still learning as I go. I am trying to create a tool gets information from remote machines and then compiles it into numbers files then zips them up. I found the above on the msdn resources :-

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PSRemoteRegistry

however when I attempt to run :- (not the actual line but similar)

```
Import-Module PSRemoteRegistry
Get-RegValue -ComputerName comp2 -Key SOFTWARE\software\software\ -Value Version
```

I get the above error, never had to digitally sign anything before and I was wondering if there was a microsft version that was signed already??

Comment: Did you already check the current ExecutionPolicy setting on your machine with the `Get-ExecutionPolicy` cmd? Note that this ExecutionPolicy can be set independently for the x64 and x86 PowerShell on a x64 machine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the PowerShell script execution policy to "unrestricted" by using the following command (make sure you run PowerShell As Administrator):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted;
```

The PSRemoteRegistry module that you downloaded from MSDN is not developed or officially supported by Microsoft. The author (Shay Levy) apparently did not sign it. This isn't really a big deal unless your script execution policy is set to RemoteSigned or AllSigned.

Comment: Before you set your execution policy to be `Unrestricted`, try setting it to something a little less dangerous... such as `RemoteSigned`, and see if it behaves better.  I just downloaded and installed the msi, and it's not giving me any issues, and I'm set as `RemoteSigned`.

Comment: Setting the execution policy to `unrestricted` isn't "dangerous." You have to go through several manual steps in order to invoke a script, so the likelihood of someone "accidentally" executing a PowerShell script is fairly low. Also, on the malicious side of things, `powershell.exe` can be invoked with the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` parameter as an admin and a non-admin.

Comment: Hmm maybe its because i just used the zip and not the msi

Comment: tried unrestricted and remote signed - unrestricted is letting me run it but getting errors on the XML:-

Microsoft.PowerShell, C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSRemoteRegistry\PSFanatic.PSRemoteRegistry.Format.ps1xml : File skipped because it was already pr
esent from "Microsoft.PowerShell".

Comment: Read the extra support bits at the bottom of the page I hadnt created the config file now seems to work :D

Comment: @TrevorSullivan, Of course it's dangerous... it's not nearly as bad as turning off the system firewall, but allowing any remote script to be run w/o some intervention is just asking to get bitten.

Comment: @HunterEidson: I don't think you are understanding. Even if the execution policy is set to the most restrictive setting `Restricted`, you can still easily execute scripts.